# Node.js basic error: Uncaught TypeError: Binance is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-modules

newbie here! I'm trying to make a basic ping to the Binance crypto exchange using its exposed REST API and node.js. Instead of coding everything from 0, I'm planning to use a wrapper package in https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-api-node that facilities interaction. I've downloaded the binance-api-node code from github into my node.js project.

After installing the package, when trying to run the included basic getting-started code to get the time from the server:

```
import Binance from 'binance-api-node';

const client = Binance();

client.time().then(time => console.log(time));
```

I’m getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Binance is not a function
```

I also tried:

```
const client = new Binance();
```

but I get another error saying Binance is not a constructor.

This is the function declaration in the index.d.ts of binance-api-node

```
    declare module 'binance-api-node' {
      export default function(options?: {
        apiKey?: string
        apiSecret?: string
        getTime?: () => number | Promise<number>
        httpBase?: string
        httpFutures?: string
        wsBase?: string
        wsFutures?: string
        proxy?: string
      }): Binance

...
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: how are you building your typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/binance-api-node):

If you do not have an appropriate babel config, you will need to use the basic commonjs requires:

```
const Binance = require('binance-api-node').default
const client = Binance();
```

Or like this, it worked for me:

```
import Binance from 'binance-api-node';
const client = Binance.default();
```

Comment: Calling the default() method on Binance did the trick! I thought it wasn't necessary since it was the "default".

Comment: @taktical9 You can accept answer if it solved your issue

Comment: mmm but in typescript i get an error because default is not a valid method